# Кракозябры в cmd при старте консольного приложения

Tags: windows, кодировка

Доброго всем дня! Вопрос думаю бородатый, но времени гуглить мало. Есть консольное приложение (утилита от oracle), которое я стартую через cmd. Вываливаются сообщения при работе приложения, которые у меня отображаются кракозябрами. Т.е. я не могу соответственно реагировать на них. Как это победить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
chcp 65001
```

или

```
chcp 1251
```

Comment: пробовал и 850 и 866 - не помогает... и шрифт менял с точечного на Consolas - все равно они вылазают.... = (

Comment: упс, пардон, щас заработало!)